# Отсутствие оформления у описания кнопок под вопросом

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Есть такое оформление у описания кнопки под вопросом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а есть например такое (при наведении на кнопку `Править`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спецификация системы (может нужно):

- **ОС** - Windows 10 версия 20H2 (сборка 19042.870)
- **Браузер** - Google Chrome Версия 89.0.4389.90 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

Я допускаю что этот функционал был протестирован, но такого вопроса здесь найти не получилось. Такое наблюдается с многими кнопками под вопросами, кроме кнопки "Отслеживать". Если что кидайте дубликат :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об этом уже написано на MSE [Use a consistent style for tooltips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349532/339911) (кстати, участником с ruSO). На текущий момент помечено меткой "отложено" и имеется ответ о том, что хотелось бы сделать, но пока не входит в ближайшие планы.

Comment: я понял, тогда об этом знают уже) спасибо большое за ответ